# <select> element is displayed with default value with dashes (---------), how to change it?

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
    class City(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.name}"


class Venue(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class VenueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = [
            'city',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VenueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city'].label = 'Град'
```

**views.py:**

```
form = VenueForm(request.POST or None)

context = {
    'form': form,
}

return render(request, "add_venue.html", context)
```

**html render:**

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
            <div class="errorcode{{field.html_name}}">
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**How it looks in browser:**

```
<select name="city" required id="id_city">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">Пловдив</option>

  <option value="2">София</option>

</select>
```

So the problem is this default value with dashed `<option value="" selected>---------</option>`.

Is there a way to remove / change it ?

There is solution in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/?fbclid=IwAR1ArsDX8U4FvoIrVztjo0OJa_6SZusn1GybNz9d_MsP18xVdAk36RSgM88#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) but it is for `ModelChoiceField` which is not my case, it is ForeighKey reference.

Comment: A `ForeignKey` in a model maps on a `ModelChoiceField` in the form. A `Form` has *no* `ForeignKeyField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is solution in docs but it is for `ModelChoiceField` which is not my case, it is `ForeighKey` reference.

A `Form` (and thus by extent a `ModelForm`) has no `ForeignKey` field, as described in the [documentation of `ModelForm`s [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) if you define a `ForeignKey` at the model level, then this corresponds to a `ModelChoiceField` in your `ModelForm`.

You thus can alter the [**`empty_label=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) with `None`:

```
class VenueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = [
            'city',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VenueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city'].label = 'Град'
        self.fields['city'].empty_label = None
```